# Do I need to use list view inside recyclerView or recyclerView inside recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I have a set of events in single recyclerView. Events are delimited by "\n". Each event in a single line. I need to populate the events in list manner( like events in Google-calendar app). So for that, Do I need to use recyclerView inside parent recyclerView or use listView inside parent recyclerView ?

[image: image_ss]

Which one will suit my needs + performance. Or Is there any other way to populate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `ListView` anymore, because it has been replaced by `RecyclerView`. I don't understand, why do you need to use `RecyclerView` inside `RecyclerView`?

If you paragraph is not very long, you can just use `TextView` inside a `ScrollView`.

If you paragraph is very long, you can use `RecyclerView` and use `TextView` as the `View` for the line item. Since `RecyclerView` use `ViewHolder` pattern, it will good for performance.

Comment: Sorry I mentioned it wrongly, it's a set of lines not a para. Each line is an history event.So i need to populate it in list manner. I will change the question.

Comment: You don't even need `RecyclerView` to show the events. `TextView` will handle it well and translate "\n" to change line directly. So you don't have to manually split the events by the delimiter.

Comment: Yeah. TextView will suit my needs. Thanks for your input